# Converting to DNF. Demorgans then moved brackets. Correct/incorrect?

Tags: first-order-logic

Disjunction normal form (DNF) consists of disjunctions of conjunctions (if I understand correctly). Ex. $(p \land q) \lor (p \land r \land s)$

I am facing this problem: $(t \implies \neg s) \land \neg t$

I have to convert to DNF.

This is my solution:

$\neg t \lor (\neg s \land \neg t)$

What I basically did was get rid of the implication sign using Demorgan's Law. Then, I moved the brackets. That's it.

Is this correct or incorrect?

Comment: Pleas use MathJax to format your mathematical expressions. See [here for a guide](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

First some corrections to your description / terminology:

**Disjunctive normal form.** A formula is in DNF if it is a disjunction of conjunctions of *literals*; here a **literal** is a propositional atom, or the negation of a propositional atom.

**Material implication** is the name of the rule that $A\to B$ is equivalent to $\lnot A\lor B$.

**De Morgan's laws** are the following laws:
\begin{align}
\lnot(A\land B)\equiv \lnot A\lor\lnot B\\
\lnot(A\lor B)\equiv \lnot A\land\lnot B
\end{align}
You don't need them in this exercise, but they are very useful in getting to normal forms, since they can bring an "outside" negation to the "inside" of a conjunction / disjunction. They have nothing to do with implications, however.

---

Now your exercise:

Your formula is equivalent by *material implication* to:
$$(t\to \lnot s)\land \lnot t\quad\equiv\quad(\lnot t\lor\lnot s)\land \lnot t$$  Simply moving the brackets around to get something resembling an answer is **not allowed**! You could make a truth table to see that the following formulas are not equivalent:
$$
p\land (q\lor r)\quad\text{ and }\quad (p\land q)\lor r
$$

What you have to do, is use the **distributivity laws**:
\begin{align}
(A\lor B)\land C\equiv(A\land C)\lor (B\land C)\\
(A\land B)\lor C\equiv(A\lor C)\land (B\lor C)
\end{align}

Using these laws we can see that: $$(\lnot t\lor\lnot s)\land\lnot t\quad\equiv\quad(\lnot t\land\lnot t)\lor(\lnot s\land \lnot t).$$

Comment: not sure what i would do without this community. being brand new to the world of logic, i greatly appreciate your help!